# What's the difference between the spin $s=h-\bar h$ and the world sheet momentum $P=L_0-\bar L_0$?

Tags: momentum, string-theory, quantum-spin, definition

> The eigenvalue under rotation is usually called the spin, $s$, and is given in terms of the weights as $s = h − \bar h$
> (Tong's string lecture notes page 75)

where

> $L_0 − \bar L_0$ generates translations in $\sigma$
> (D-Branes Clifford V. Johnson Page 42) [and was called] the [world sheet] momentum $P=L_0-\bar L_0$
> (D-Branes Clifford V. Johnson Page 91)

Where we knew that, for a primary $L_0-\bar L_0|\phi\rangle= h-\bar h|\phi\rangle$ and the condition for the physical states were

> $L_0-\bar L_0|\phi\rangle =0$
> (D-Branes Clifford V. Johnson Page 42)

What's the difference between the spin $s=h-\bar h$ and the world sheet momentum $P=L_0-\bar L_0$? Is the physical states in the CFT all spin zero? (a similar comparison was $H=L_0+\bar L_0-c/24\sim h+\bar h$ the scaling dimension, but the story there seemed to be quite standard.)